# MATLAB: imagesc() and image() display the same colormap differently

Tags: matlab

I have some data I would like to display in a picture form. In one case I want to rescale the x and y axis, which leads me to using `imagesc`. The issue is that the same colormap (jet) looks different in `imagesc` as compared to `image`.

**Is there a way to make them the same?**

I am using MATLAB R2014a.

Demonstration:

Here is how I show them:

```
figure; image(cancelledmap); colormap(jet);          %image
figure; imagesc(y,x,cancelledmap); colormap(jet);    %imagesc
```

And the output:

[image]

The colormap settings for both figures are somehow the same, however:

[image: image()]

[image: imagesc()]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`imagesc` scales the color axis, whereas `image` does not. That's why the colors look different. If you click the colorbar button you'll see that they are on different color scales.

You can change the colorscale with `caxis`.

By the way, if you only want to scale the X- and Y-axes, you can use either function. Just supply your own scaled `x` and `y` vectors.